# Чередование положительных/отрицательных значений

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, 
Есть БД SQL с таблицей изменения стоимости товаров. Необходимо написать запрос, который выводит строки, в которых изменился знак на противоположный. То есть в примере должны выводится 1,2,3 строки, т.к. 1-положительное значение;2-отрицательное;3-положительное. Как я понимаю необходимо создать дополнительную таблицу и проверять с помощью inner join. Подскажите, если кто знает (в таблице порядка 600000 строк).

[image: Стоимость товаров]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ID идут по порядку, то

```
select * from (select top 1 * from CostChanges order by id) as first
union all
select c2.* from CostChanges c1 
inner join CostChanges c2 on c1.ID = c2.ID - 1
where 
    (c1.Change >= 0 and c2.Change < 0) or (c1.Change =< 0 and c2.Change > 0)
```

Если не по порядку - добавляйте row number:

```
;with ordered as 
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID asc) as rn from CostChanges
)
select * from ordered where rn = 1
union all
select c2.* from ordered c1 
inner join ordered c2 on c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
where 
    (c1.Change >= 0 and c2.Change < 0) or (c1.Change =< 0 and c2.Change > 0)
```

Comment: Спасибо Паша, но можно ли добавить условие, чтобы не повторялись соседние значения? Первый вариант мне помог, но если идут одинаковые значения с одним знаком, то запрос выводит оба

Comment: @PASE7 в каком смысле  "не повторялись соседние"? можете привести пример данных?

Comment: картинку прикрепить не могу,т.к. мало голосов. Например: Первая строка Change = -1,1 ; вторая = -1,1; Третья = -1,1. Выводятся все три, далее - положительное

Comment: @PASE7 такого точно не должно быть - запрос фильтрует именно это - между первой -1.1 и второй -1.1 должна быть выбрана строка с положительным change. попробуйте добавить в конце запроса order by 1 - может быть у вас просто результат не по порядку выводится. ну или отредатируйте свой вопрос и приведите пример проблемных данных.

Comment: Понял в чем дело, запрос возвращает значения c2, в бд много значений вида: -10,1 ; 12,1 ; 0 ; 0 ; -10,1 ; 10,1 . Поэтому бывают моменты, когда запрос возвращает 12,1 ; 10,1 по очереди

Comment: @PASE7 так проблема в том, что в последовательности встречаются 0, и переход с 0 на -1 или на 1 считается сменой знака. или наоборот, не считается? Тогда достаточно просто исправить условие, чтобы учитывать 0